# Square root scale using matplotlib/python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, scale

I want to make a plot with square root scale using Python:

[image: square root scale graph]

However, I have no idea how to make it. Matplotlib allows to make log scale but in this case I need something like power function scale.

Comment: Look inside: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/custom_scale_example.html

Comment: This answer shows how to get a custom scale using the `function` mode of the set_scale commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198022/4742780

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make your own [`ScaleBase`](http://matplotlib.org/api/scale_api.html#matplotlib.scale.ScaleBase) class to do this. I have modified the example from [here](http://statingthebleedingobvious.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/problems-with-creating-a-new-matplotlib-scalebase-class/) (which made a square-scale, not a square-root-scale) for your purposes. Also, see the documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/devel/add_new_projection.html).

Note that to do this properly, you should probably also create your own custom tick locator; I haven't done that here though; I just manually set the major and minor ticks using `ax.set_yticks()`.

```
import matplotlib.scale as mscale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

class SquareRootScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
    """
    ScaleBase class for generating square root scale.
    """
 
    name = 'squareroot'
 
    def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
        # note in older versions of matplotlib (<3.1), this worked fine.
        # mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self)

        # In newer versions (>=3.1), you also need to pass in `axis` as an arg
        mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self, axis)
 
    def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
        axis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
        axis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
        axis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
        axis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
 
    def limit_range_for_scale(self, vmin, vmax, minpos):
        return  max(0., vmin), vmax
 
    class SquareRootTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True
 
        def transform_non_affine(self, a): 
            return np.array(a)**0.5
 
        def inverted(self):
            return SquareRootScale.InvertedSquareRootTransform()
 
    class InvertedSquareRootTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True
 
        def transform(self, a):
            return np.array(a)**2
 
        def inverted(self):
            return SquareRootScale.SquareRootTransform()
 
    def get_transform(self):
        return self.SquareRootTransform()
 
mscale.register_scale(SquareRootScale)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.plot(np.arange(0, 9)**2, label='$y=x^2$')
ax.legend()

ax.set_yscale('squareroot')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,9,2)**2)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,8.5,0.5)**2, minor=True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but I made a quick-fix because i didn't want to bother with creating a custom tick-locator. If you are making a lot of plots with custom scales that is probably the way to go. Just plotting the function with the scale you want, then setting the ticks and changing the labels is quicker if you just need a plot or two.

```
Nx = 100
x = np.linspace(0,50,Nx)
y = np.sqrt(x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

plt.plot(np.sqrt(x), y)
ax.set_xticks([np.sqrt(x[i]) for i in range(0, Nx, Nx // 10)])
ax.set_xticklabels([str(round(x[i],0))[:-2] for i in range(0, Nx, Nx // 10)])
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel(r'y = $\sqrt{x}$')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

produces the plot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like lolopop's comment and tom's answer, a more quick and dirty solution would be using [set_yticks and set_yticklabels](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels) as in the following:

```
x = np.arange(2, 15, 2)
y = x * x

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

ax1.plot(x,y)

ax2.plot(x, np.sqrt(y))
ax2.set_yticks([2,4,6,8,10,12,14])
ax2.set_yticklabels(['4','16','36','64','100','144','196'])
```

Comment: as far as I understand "tick mechanics" it will just force false labales. Plot axes will look like square root scale, but data display won't transform, thus plot will be completely misleading.

Comment: @michal_2am Agreed. Its bad practice to disassociate the tick labels from the data

Answer (score 0):

Use `matplotlib.scale.FuncScale`. It's essentially a one liner, taking the scale function and its inverse. You can add custom ticks and etc later, if you want it to look good:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Start a figure.
ax: plt.Axes
fig: plt.Figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Set the y axis scale of the figure to a sqrt scale.
func = lambda e: e**0.5
inv_func = lambda e: e**2
ax.set_yscale(matplotlib.scale.FuncScale(ax, (func, inv_func)))

# Demonstrate.
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ys = [1, 4, 64, 16, 25]
ax.plot(xs, ys)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Matplotlib now offers a powlaw norm. Thus setting power to 0.5 should do the trick!

C.f. [Matplotlib Powerlaw norm](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormapnorms.html)

And their example:

```
"""
Demonstration of using norm to map colormaps onto data in non-linear ways.
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib.mlab import bivariate_normal

N = 100
X, Y = np.mgrid[-3:3:complex(0, N), -2:2:complex(0, N)]

'''
PowerNorm: Here a power-law trend in X partially obscures a rectified
sine wave in Y. We can remove gamma to 0.5 should do the trick using  PowerNorm.
'''
X, Y = np.mgrid[0:3:complex(0, N), 0:2:complex(0, N)]
Z1 = (1 + np.sin(Y * 10.)) * X**(2.)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

pcm = ax[0].pcolormesh(X, Y, Z1, norm=colors.PowerNorm(gamma=1./2.),
                       cmap='PuBu_r')
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax[0], extend='max')

pcm = ax[1].pcolormesh(X, Y, Z1, cmap='PuBu_r')
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax[1], extend='max')
fig.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was about changing the axis scale to a square root scale. This answer shows how to change the colormap norm to a square root norm; which while interesting, does not help the original question