# Trying to make a cubed ScaleBase class in matplotlib, but I can't get it working. Any Ideas?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have applied a cubed transformation to some data that I am trying to plot. Since, matplotlib doesn't have a built-in cubed scale, I am trying to create one using a `ScaleBase` class.

I used these two examples as references ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277989/square-root-scale-using-matplotlib-python), [example 2](https://statingthebleedingobvious.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/problems-with-creating-a-new-matplotlib-scalebase-class/)), but after modifying these examples for my planned cubed scale, I couldn't get it working. The `ScaleBase` class, which in my code is `CubedScale`, for whatever reason has no affect on the plot. I will show both plots below, one without `CubedScale` and one with.

Plot without my `CubedScale` class applied:

```
plt.plot(np.cbrt(np.arange(0,9)))
plt.show();
```

[image]

Code to create `CubedScale` class:

```
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.scale as mscale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class CubedScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
'''
ScaleBase class for generating cubed scale.
'''

name = 'cubed'

def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
    mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self, axis)
    
def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
    axis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
    axis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
    axis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
    axis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())

def limit_range_for_scale(self, vmin, vmax, minpos):
    return max(0., vmin), vmax

class CubedTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
    input_dims = 1
    output_dims = 1
    is_separable = True
    
    def transform(self, a):
        return np.array(a)**3
    
    def inverted(self): 
        return CubedScale.InvertedCubedTransform()
    
class InvertedCubedTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
    input_dims = 1
    output_dims = 1
    is_separable = True
    
    def transform(self, a):
        return np.cbrt(np.array(a))
    
    def inverted(self):
        return CubedScale.CubedTransform()

def get_transform(self):
    return self.CubedTransform()

mscale.register_scale(CubedScale)
```

Plot after applying `CubedScale`:

```
plt.plot(np.cbrt(np.arange(0,9)))
plt.gca().set_yscale('cubed')
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,9)**(1/3))
plt.show();
```

[image]

So, you can see here that `CubedScale` is created successfully, but it does to transform the scale. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may have posted the same plot twice?

Comment: Nope, just showing that the `CubedScale` class doesn't have any effect after it is applied to the second plot in `plt.gca().set_yscale('cubed')`. I will edit the first plot to show the code for it.

Answer (score 2):

Solution Found:

Creating a new `ScaleBase` class here is unnecessary and cumbersome.

Instead, we can use `FuncScale` and the 'function' option of `set_xscale` and `set_yscale`. You can refer to this [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/scales/scales.html) in matplotlib docs.

This is the code that ended up working and the resulting plot:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

def forward(x):
    return x**3

def inverse(x):
    return np.sign(x) * (np.abs(x)) ** (1 / 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(np.cbrt(np.arange(0,9)))
ax.set_yscale('function', functions=(forward, inverse))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(FixedLocator(np.arange(0, 10, 1)**(1/3)))
```

[image]

This is what I was trying to achieve in the op. A cubed transformation of the y-axis.