# How to make the x-axis scale as a^3?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to plot a figure like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

x = [1**3, 2**3, 3**3, 4**3, 5**3] # i.e., [1,8,27,64,125]
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I'd like to make the x-axis scaling look like 'log' scale. But instead of being 10^n, the tick labels should be located at a^3 (a=1, 2, 3, 4, 5). I am preciate if you could share some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a logscale for the x-axis, and explicitly set the ticks and ticklabels:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import NullLocator

x = [1**3, 2**3, 3**3, 4**3, 5**3] # i.e., [1,8,27,64,125]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xticks(x, [f'${i}^3$' for i in range(1, 6)])
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(NullLocator()) # remove the minor ticks created by plt.xscale('log')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: If you want the x-ticks equally spaced, you could adapt the code from [Square root scale using matplotlib/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277989/square-root-scale-using-matplotlib-python) to third roots.

Comment: Nice, I'd like to try both.