# Custom scales do not work with panning/zooming

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I'm trying to write custom scales for Matplotlib, and overall it works great but the issue is that it breaks panning and zooming. Here's a minimum working example, which comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277989/square-root-scale-using-matplotlib-python).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.scale as mscale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

class SquareRootScale(mscale.ScaleBase):
    """
    ScaleBase class for generating square root scale.
    """
 
    name = 'squareroot'
 
    def __init__(self, axis, **kwargs):
        # note in older versions of matplotlib (<3.1), this worked fine.
        # mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self)

        # In newer versions (>=3.1), you also need to pass in `axis` as an arg
        mscale.ScaleBase.__init__(self, axis)
 
    def set_default_locators_and_formatters(self, axis):
        axis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
        axis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
        axis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
        axis.set_minor_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
 
    def limit_range_for_scale(self, vmin, vmax, minpos):
        return  max(0., vmin), vmax
 
    class SquareRootTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True
 
        def transform_non_affine(self, a): 
            return np.array(a)**0.5
 
        def inverted(self):
            return SquareRootScale.InvertedSquareRootTransform()
 
    class InvertedSquareRootTransform(mtransforms.Transform):
        input_dims = 1
        output_dims = 1
        is_separable = True
 
        def transform(self, a):
            return np.array(a)**2
 
        def inverted(self):
            return SquareRootScale.SquareRootTransform()
 
    def get_transform(self):
        return self.SquareRootTransform()
 


def main():
    mscale.register_scale(SquareRootScale)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

    ax.plot(np.arange(0, 9)**2, label='$y=x^2$')
    ax.legend()

    ax.set_yscale('squareroot')
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,9,2)**2)
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,8.5,0.5)**2, minor=True)

    plt.show()
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem however, is that panning and zooming completely miscalculate the new axes ranges. It seems that at the beginning of the panning action, it sets the scaled axes to the square root immediately. Then during the panning action the movement is not linear either.

My guess is therefore that it tries to calculate the x and y coordinates from my mouse pointer, but doesn't know that the axis is scaled differently than expected. Zooming is equally messed up. I've tried playing around in the `drag_pan` functions in the canvas module, but I cannot figure out how to compensate for this. Does anyone have any ideas what would be the best way to figure this out.

Here's a screencast with the behaviour: https://streamable.com/fww7ch

I don't think it matters too much. But for completeness sake, I'm using Python 3.10 with Matplotlib 3.7.1. I'm running this all on Fedora Silverblue, using the Cairo backend of Matplotlib.

I have tried using different Matplotlib versions (3.6.0) to no avail. I've also tried to look into the canvas module, and modify the `axes.drag_pan` method, but unfortuantely that did not really work out. Indeed, the scaling can be modified like this, but just setting my x coordinates during pan to the square root (or square) did not seem to solve my problem.

Comment: In your `InvertedSquareTransform` the quadratic is also a `transform_non_affine`, not a `transform`.